# Update/destroy Rails model via AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, post

I'm trying to update my Rails model by using AJAX calls from front-end, but can't implement it correctly.

My routes are:

```
  authenticated :customer do
    post 'update_card/:id', to: 'customers/cards#update'
    post 'delete_card/:id', to: 'customers/cards#destroy'
  end
```

Here's my controller that handles the requests:

```
class Customers::CardsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_customer!

  def update
    if customer_signed_in?
      card_to_update = JSON.parse(params)

      card = current_customer.discount_cards.find(params[:id])

     # do the update... (update_attributes ?)

      render json: card
    end
    render status: :not_found, json: 'error'
  end

  def destroy
    # nothing yet
  end
end
```

and this is how I do the AJAX call:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: `/update_card/${this.props.cardId}.json`,
        data: JSON.stringify({
            name: newName,
            description: newDesc,
            shopName: newShopName,
        }),
        success: (msg) => {
            console.log('Data Saved: ' + msg);
        },
    });
```

I can't figure out what I'm missing and keep getting this error:

> TypeError - no implicit conversion of ActionController::Parameters
>   into String

---

Could you please help me with implementing the update and destroy methods correctly?

---

## Update

I've changed my `update` method and now it looks like this:

```
  def update
    if customer_signed_in?

      card = current_customer.discount_cards.find(params[:id])

      card.name ||= params[:name]
      card.description ||= params[:description]
      card.shop.name = params[:shopName] if params[:shopName] && card.shop

      card.save!
      current_customer.save!

      render json: { status: 'updated', object: card.to_json }
    else
      render json: { status: 'failed', errors: ['error'] }
    end
  end
```

and also now there's no `JSON.stringify` call in ajax

However, the data doesn't get saved. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JSON.parse` method allow as an argument a string not the hash.

```
card_to_update = JSON.parse(params)
```

`params` is a `ActionController::Parameters`, a hash in the rails env.

Why you need to `JSON.stringify`? Pass to the `data` just an object.

```
data: {
   name: newName,
   description: newDesc,
   shopName: newShopName
},
```

Then use it in Rails:

```
# some code here
card_to_update = { name: params[:name],
                   description: params[:description],
                   shopName: params[:shopName] }
# some code here
```

Or another version:

```
data: { toUpdate: {
   name: newName,
   description: newDesc,
   shopName: newShopName
} },
```

Rails:

```
card_to_update = params[:toUpdate]
```

Comment: I've edited my `update` method according to your advice, but now it doesn't save the data. Do you have any ideas what it is so?

Comment: But this is another question. Also why you use `||=` instead of `=` ? And what you mean by `doesn't save`, any error? what is inside the Rails log file?